# Finding entries in a join table with identical links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

In my chat app I have `users` and `chats`. The tables for each of these is connected by a join table:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats_users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats, :through => :chats_users
end

class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats_users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :through => :chats_users
end

class ChatsUsers < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :chat, class_name: 'Chat'
    belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'
    validates :ad_id, presence: true
    validates :tag_id, presence: true
end
```

And the inverse in `chat.rb`.

When creating a new chat with a list of participating list of `user_id`s, I want to first check a chat doesn't already exist with the exact same list of associated `user_id`s, but I can't work out a sane way to do this. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you add both the chat and chat_user models?

Comment: Didn't think they were necessary sorry, here you are.

Comment: Does your chats_users table have an id (primary key) column?

Comment: It doesn't. I can add one if that would be a good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is only used in the case where you do not need a join model (or where you initially think you don't need it) as its headless. Instead you want to use `has_many through:`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :chat_users
  has_many :chats, through: :chat_users
end

class Chat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chat_users
  has_many :users, through: :chat_users
end

class ChatUser < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :chat
   belongs_to :user
   # not needed if these are belongs_to associations in Rails 5+
   validates :ad_id, presence: true
   validates :tag_id, presence: true
end
```

You may need to create a migration to change the name of your table to `chat_users` and make sure it has a primary key.

`has_and_belongs_to_many` uses an oddball `plural_plural` naming scheme that will cause rails to infer that the class is named `Chats::User` since plural words are treated as modules. While you can work around that by explicitly listing the class name its better to just align your schema [with the conventions](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions).

If your still just messing about in development roll back and delete the migration that created the join table and run `rails g model ChatUser chat:belongs_to user:belongs_to` to generate the correct table with a primary key and timestamps.

If you want to select chats connected to a given set of users:

```
users = [1,2,3]
Chat.joins(:users)
    .where(users: { id: users })
    .group(:id)
    .having(User.arel_table[Arel.star].count.eq(users.length))
    .exists?
```

Note that you don't really need to tell ActiveRecord which table its going through. Thats the beauty of indirect associations.